# .NET Braintree : Transactions sent as charged for settlement never settled

Tags: braintree

I am integrating Braintree payment option in a site, currently in sand box. The setup was easy, docs helped a lot but I am confused about one thing.

When I submit a transaction as a settlement, it processes the transaction and also shows in transactions in the control panel but it is never settled. I want to know how can I be sure if the customer was charged so I can deliver the service he requested.

If an amount does not settle, and I have delivered the product then It will be a problem for my client.

It is showing all the transactions as this, including the paypal ones.
Please see the attached screen shot.

**The code I am using:**

```
    var request = new TransactionRequest
                {
                    Amount = 33.22,
                    PaymentMethodNonce = nonce,
                    OrderId = CustomerOrderId,
                    Options = new TransactionOptionsRequest
                    {
                        SubmitForSettlement = true
                    }
                };
```

[image: Screen shot of transaction in control panel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually BrainTree Settles all the transaction with in a time period(it may take a day).

**submitted_for_settlement:** This means a transaction has made which would get settled, but not immediately when the transaction occurs.

The real settlement happens under **Disbursement**, this runs daily and here they will disburse all the transactions which are in *submitted_for_settlement* status and during this process only

I would suggest you to add **Disbursement Webhook** in to your application, this helps you to get all the details of the disbursement from braintree.

Don't forget to save the **Disbursement ID** value, which you will get from *disbursement webhook* ONLY. We cannot see the disbursement ID in their console.

Use of **Disbursement ID** - this ID will be in the buyers **CC Billing**

To implement this please follow this docs.

1. https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/webhooks/disbursement/dotnet
2. https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/webhooks/parse/dotnet

Comment: so I can be sure that "submitted_for_settlement" will be transferred to my account, or it can be rejected after that also. I am just confused about when can I be sure. Definitely I cannot make a person wait for 1 day to check if it is Disbursed or not to deliver the service. It should be like the customer paid and I sent him the product.

Comment: Yes you can be sure on this, since customer has charged. Disbursement never fails in max case, because this transaction has made after all verification which you have enabled. Even after in rare case disbursement fails means you have to deal this with braintree. In my integration I have seen thousands of transactions where I never seen any single disbursement failure.